# Chebyshev’s Theorem and Lightbulbs

Tags: probability

> "An electrical firm manufactures a 100-watt light bulb, which, according to
>   specifications written on the package, has a mean life of 900 hours with a standard deviation of 50 hours. At most, what percentage of the bulbs fails to last even 700 hours?
>
> Assume that the distribution is symmetric about the mean."

I tried for quite a while, but failed to get the correct answer.

So far, this is what I have:

$\begin{align}
\Pr(X < 700) &= Pr(X - 900 < - 200) \\
&= Pr(|X - 900| > 200) \\
&= Pr(|X - 900| > 4(50)) \le(\frac{1}{4})^2, or\ 0.0625\\
\end{align}$

But the answer was quite different from what I had.

Edit: For the sake of convenience, the answer (thanks to André Nicolas & Dahn):

$\begin{align}
\Pr(X < 700) &= Pr(X - 900 < - 200) \\
&= \frac{Pr(|X - 900| > 200)}{2} \\
&= \frac{Pr(|X - 900| > 4(50))}{2} \le(\frac{1}{4})^2 \times \frac{1}{2}, \ or\ 0.03125\\
\end{align}$

Comment: If we are to assume symmetry divide by $2$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Yes! That gives the correct answer. But I still don't understand why. Would it be ok if you gave a more detailed explanation?

Comment: The Chebyshev Inequality says that $\Pr(|X-\mu|\ge k\sigma)\le \frac{1}{k^2}$. In our case we have $\mu=900$, $\sigma=50$, so $k=4$. (You knew all this). Thus the **sum** of the probabilities of being in the left tail or right tail is $1/16$. By symmetry the probability of being in the left tail is $(1/2)(1/16)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression $|X-900|>200$ means "$X$ is at least 200 hours away from 900", i.e. $X$ is less than $700$ or higher than $1100$. If we assume symmetry, the probability of either of those is half, thus you needed to divide your answer by half to only get the probability of being less than $700$.

This then, however, means you've got a mistake somewhere in your calculation, as one of the equal signs cannot be right. Can you spot the place?